# What Is the Best Way to Perform a Search and Replace On only Specific Sections of a File?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, substitution

I have a markdown file with sections separated by headings. I want to perform a search and replace only on specific sections; however, each section has similar content, so a global search and replace would end up affecting all sections. Because of this, I would need to somehow limit the search and replace to only certain sections of the file.

For example, say I wanted to replace *all* instances of `foo` with `bar` under `# Section 1`, `# Section 3`, and `# Section 4` leaving `# Section 2` and `# Section 5` unchanged, as shown below

Sample Input:

```markdown
# Section 1

- foo
- foo
- Unimportant Item
- foo
- Unimportant Item

# Section 2

- foo
- Unimportant Item

# Section 3

- foo
- Unimportant Item

# Section 4

- foo
- Unimportant Item
- foo

# Section 5

- foo
- foo
```

Sample Output

```markdown
# Section 1

- bar
- bar
- Unimportant Item
- bar
- Unimportant Item

# Section 2

- foo
- Unimportant Item

# Section 3

- bar
- Unimportant Item

# Section 4

- bar
- Unimportant Item
- bar

# Section 5

- foo
- foo
```

If I didn't have to worry about the individual sections, a global search and replace would be trivial by using

```sh
sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' <input_file>
```

but I'm not sure if `sed` is capable of checking context to allow what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completion, this awk answer will do the substitutions in the whole section, including the header:

```
awk '/^#/ { in_section = /Section [1|3|4]/ } in_section { sub(/foo/, "bar") } 1' input.md
```

If you want to exclude the headers from the substitution:

```
awk ' /^#/ { in_section = /Section [1|3|4]/; header_line = NR }
      in_section && (NR > header_line) { sub(/foo/, "bar") } 1' input.md
```

Detail

```
awk '/^#/ {                              # if in section header
        in_section = /Section [1|3|4]/;    # determine if section of interest (1/0)
        header_line = NR;                # value of header line to exclude
    }
    in_section && (NR > header_line) {   # if in section of interest and after header line
        sub(/foo/, "bar");               # substitute text
    } 1' input.md                        # 1 is to print all lines
```

Comment: So far, this is the most accurate, and general answer!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sed version:

```
sed -E '/^#[^#]\s*Section\s+[134]\s*$/, // s/foo/bar/' input.md
```

Comment: What does separating the separate regex with the comma do?

Comment: The two regex expressions separated with a comma represents an address range in sed. Anything outside of that range is ignored by sed. The end of the range is a blank line.

Comment: I just tried /#/ for end of the range and that works too.

Comment: I expected that you may need to tune the re patterns in the range. I'll play with it

Comment: I've updated the regex expressions in the sed range. Does this help? I tested it against your updated samples.

Comment: If you can update your question with the input that causes my solution to fail, I'll work on it some more.

Comment: I changed the end pattern of the range to an empty regular expression. This repeats the last matched regex. When I diff the output of the updated command, it matches your expected results.

Comment: My guess is the regex address range is like a multi-line match that is active until the start pattern is encountered again. So the empty end pattern seems to be making the address range non-greedy. Still trying to wrap my head around that!

Comment: Good idea! I'll watch for it. And you're welcome.

Comment: SO asked if I wanted  to [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230826/discussion-between-cole-tierney-and-kalcifer). Just trying out the feature.

Comment: **EDIT**: I have removed all of my previous outdated comments.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'p {sub(/foo$/, "bar")} /^#/ {p = / (Section [134])$/} 1' file
# Section 1

- bar
- bar
- Unimportant Item
- bar
- Unimportant Item

# Section 2

- foo
- Unimportant Item

# Section 3

- bar
- Unimportant Item

# Section 4

- bar
- Unimportant Item
- bar

# Section 5

- foo
- foo
```

To make it more readable:

```sh
awk 'p {                          # if p==1 and current line # == n
   sub(/foo$/, "bar")             # replace foo with bar
}
/^#/ {                            # if line starts with #
   p = / (Section [134])$/        # set p = 1/0 if it matches sections
} 1' file
```

Comment: @Kalcifer Based on your comment I have updated my answer. Please check

Comment: This answer doesn't work. It only does the substitution on the second line following the section header, not on the whole section.

Comment: I have realized a flaw with this answer: It will fail if there are multiple instances of `foo` within a section. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: **EDIT**: I have removed all of my outdated comments.

Comment: @Kalcifer: I have modified my answer based on latest edited question

Answer (score 0):

My usual advice whenever you're considering `sed -i` is to use its older brother `ed` instead, as unlike `sed`, it's intended from the get-go to edit files (It's also POSIX standard, unlike `sed -i`, and thus more portable.)

Something like

```sh
ed -s input.md <<EOF
/Section 1/;/Section/s/foo/bar/g
/Section 3/;/Section/sg
w
EOF
```

Translated: In the block starting with the first line containing `Section 1` and ending with the next `Section` line, replace `foo` with `bar`. Then do the same **s**ubstitution in the `Section 3` block. Finally, **w**rite the changes back to disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can always provide multiple commands to `sed` with the `-e` option so that substitution occurs even when the sections are one after another:

```
sed  -e '/# Section 1/,/#/ s/foo/bar/' -e '/# Section 2/,/#/ s/foo/bar/' input.md
```

Multiple commands can also be placed in a "sed script file":

```
# content of script.sed
/# Section 1/,/#/ s/foo/bar/
/# Section 2/,/#/ s/foo/bar/
```

And you executed like this:

```
sed  -f script.sed input.md
```

Comment: This is an option; however, it would unfortunately become very tedious if I had hundreds of sections.

Comment: @Kalcifer, only if you want changes to sections that are one after the other. You can always use a regex as the first portion of the range. For instance if you wanted to change Section 1, 2 and 3, you could do: `sed -e '/# Section [13]/,/#/ s/foo/bar/' -e '/# Section 2/,/#/ s/foo/bar/' input.md`, but I get your point. It is not as elegant and uniform. I'm still thinking how to make it work with one command. If it comes to me, I'll add another answer.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `sed`

The key is in the range. The first addressing pattern matches the header(s) where we want the substitution to begin, and the second, matches all headers except the ones in the first addressing pattern. Note that the substitute command is inclusive of the first and last lines in the range (i.e. the headers).

```
sed -E '/^# Section [134]/, /^# Section [^134]/ s/foo/bar/' input.md
```

This one excludes the headers from the substitution:

```
sed -E '/^# Section [134]/, /^# Section [^134]/ { /^#/!s/foo/bar/ }' input.md
```

Comment: While I do love the elegance of this solution, it wouldn’t work as a general solution where the sections aren’t so nicely numbered.

Comment: @Kalcifer , yes, you're right. You would have to work on the "opposite" regular expression for your end of section, and it may not be as simple as in your example. However, if it is simple, then, this works well, so I figured that I'd point it out in case that it helps someone. Plus, I thought about it after many hours of analyzing the "empty" regex `//` in @cole-tierney 's response. I now understand it, and why it didn't work!

Comment: RE: "the "empty" regex", you may find interest in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66980225/7934600) answer.