# What Does an Empty Regular Expression in a Sed Address Range Do?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, substitution

The following command `sed -E '/# Section [134]/, // s/foo/bar/' <input_file>` accomplishes the following

Input

```markdown
# Section 1

- foo
- Unimportant Item

# Section 2

- foo
- Unimportant Item

# Section 3

- foo
- Unimportant Item

# Section 4

- foo
- Unimportant Item

# Section 5

- foo
- Unimportant Item
```

Output

```markdown
# Section 1

- bar
- Unimportant Item

# Section 2

- foo
- Unimportant Item

# Section 3

- bar
- Unimportant Item

# Section 4

- bar
- Unimportant Item

# Section 5

- foo
- Unimportant Item
```

I am unsure of how this command works, specifically the empty regular expression in the address range. What I understand so far is Sed will first look for a portion of the document that matches the following regex `/# Section [134]/`, if it matches, it will begin the substitution looking for matches for `foo` and replacing them with `bar`. The second portion of the address range, as far as I am aware, is the stopping point, but in this case it is empty. I read [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html) that an empty regular expression  "repeats the last regular expression match", but I don't exactly know what this means, or how it affects this specific Sed command. How does the address range know that the stopping point is after each section? What regex is `//` repeating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me simplify the input file as:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
```

and the test script as:

```
sed -n "/[134]/,//p"
```

which will print the all lines, corresponding to your test results.
As noted, the empty regex repeats the previous regex, then the sed command
above is equivalent to:

```
sed -n "/[134]/,/[134]/p"
```

BTW the address range operator of `sed` works as follows:

- If the `left` address matches, returns true *without* evaluating
  `right` address on the same line (unlike the range operator of `awk` which evaluates the right
  condition immediately on the same line).

Let's see how the operator works line by line.

- On the first line `Line1`, the left start address matches and
  returns `true`.
- On the second line, the right stop address is evaluated  without
  match then the operator keeps `true`.
- On the third line, the right stop address matches then it
  changes the status to `false` (*after* printing the line).
- On the fourh line, the left start address matches and
  returns `true` again.
- On the fifth line, the right stop address does not match and keeps `true`.

If you change the regex to `/[135]/`, you will see a different result.
(Line1, 2, 3, 5 will be printed skipping Line4.)

Comment: Thank you! The important part for me to note was that the empty regex will include the regex in the search and replace command as the most recent match witch was the source of my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Using an empty regex is a shorthand for repeating the latest matching regex.  So your script is an abbreviated (and more idiomatic, and less buggy) version of the longhand

```sh
sed -E '/# Section [134]/,/# Section [134]/ s/foo/bar/' <input_file>
```

which says to perform the substitution `s/foo/bar/` in the range of lines starting with one occurrence of the regex, through to the next occurrence of the same regex (and starting again if there is a third one up through the fourth one, etc).

This is also available in the `s///` command, so a fairly common idiom is

```sh
sed '/foo/ s//bar/'
```

which says to search for `foo` and then replace `foo` with `bar`. (This particular example is not particularly useful, but there are situations where this saves a lot of typing.)

Comment: What confuses me is the part where you said it’s equivalent to `/# Section [134]/, /# Section [134]/`. I understand *why* it’s equivalent to that, but what I don’t understand is how it accomplishes what it does in the example. From what I can understand of it, it will look for where it finds section 1, 3, or 4, and then it will begin the search and replace, stopping when it encounters section 1, 3, or 4; however, this can’t be so, as in the example it performs the search and replace for section 1, skips section 2, and restarts at 3. I would essentially expect it to never stop.

Comment: Weird. You're right. If I change the command to `sed -nE '/# Section [134]/, // p'` I see exactly the lines I expect, but https://ideone.com/ZLNYy7 shows the behavior you describe.